# Anyone know why it won't printf the result

Tags: c

I was wondering why my code won't execute the `printf`?
So the code input consists of `T`, the number of testcases. For each case, there are `N`, `M`, number of rows and columns in someone's house plan. Then, `N` lines follow, which consist of `M` characters describing his/her house plan information.

```
#include<stdio.h>

char image[1000][1000];
int row,col;
int tileCount = 0;

bool valid(int i,int j)
{
    if(i<0 || i>=row || j<0 || j>=col)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}

void floodFill(int x, int y)
{
    if(valid(x,y) == false)           
        return;
    if(image[x][y] == '#')
        return;
    if(image[x][y] == '.'){
        image[x][y] = '#'; 
        tileCount++;
    }                  
    floodFill(x-1,y);
    floodFill(x+1,y);
    floodFill(x,y-1);
    floodFill(x,y+1);
}

int main()
{
    int t;
    scanf("%d", &t);
    for(int i=1; i<=t; i++){
        tileCount = 0;
        int x, y; 
    
        scanf("%d %d", &row, &col);
        for(int k=0;k<row;k++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<col;j++)
            {
                scanf("%d", &image[k][j]);
                //getchar();
                if(image[k][j] == 'S'){
                    x = k;
                    y = j;
                }
            }
            getchar();
           }
        
        floodFill(x,y);
        
        printf("Case #%d: %d\n", i, tileCount);
        
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Output should be expressed in format

> Case #X: Y

Where X is number of floors (tiles) to be
replaced in Xth case.

I tried many things, but I still can't solve the problem.

Comment: Now would be a good time to learn to effectively debug your own code. Run your program in a debugger and see exactly what it is doing. Surely you should be able to at least work out what code path it is running or stuck in. [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: @Goldi, Save time and enable all warnings to quickly see trouble with `scanf("%d", &image[k][j]);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing to learn is to set your compiler to a high warning level and to treat all warnings as errors. For instance for `gcc` you should compile using the options `-Wall -Wextra -Werror`.

That would have told about a type mismatch in the code `scanf("%d", &image[k][j]);` as you scan for intergers (`%d`) but store the result in a char-array.

Further, it would tell that `x` and `y` might be uninitialized (i.e. in case the user never gave `'S'` as input).

"Correct" compiler options would have helped detecting these issues.

Now for the `floodFill` function imagine that you call it with `(0, 0)` and that `image[0][0]` and `image[1][0]` contains values different from both `'#'` and `'.'`.

That will - in principle - lead to the follwing code:

```
floodFill(0, 0)
{
    ....

    floodFill(-1, 0);
    floodFill(1, 0);
    floodFill(0, -1);
    floodFill(0, 1);
}
```

The call `floodFill(-1, 0)` will just return as it's not valid but for `floodFill(1, 0);` the code will be:

```
floodFill(1, 0)
{
    ....

    floodFill(0, 0);  <------ ups, calling with (0, 0) again
    floodFill(2, 0);
    floodFill(1, -1);
    floodFill(1, 1);
}
```

Notice how this leads to a new call of `floodFill(0, 0)`. In other words - you have created an endless loop like:

```
floodFill(0, 0) -> floodFill(1, 0) -> floodFill(0, 0) -> floodFill(1, 0) -> ...
```

So nothing will be printed and the program will (most likely) crash due to a stack overflow.